# Incorrectly identifying many:many relationships between table columns

Tags: sql, r, database, relationship, data-analysis

I have written a script in R to find relationships between columns in different tables. However, I'm getting "many:many" relationships between columns that are clearly not related. I suspect that the issue lies in the get_relationship function logic. Can anyone suggest a better logic for the get_relationship function?

I am using the following code which includes a query function to retrieve data from a PostgreSQL database. However, I have implemented query 2 in the code below to store the values of previous queries to reduce execution time.

```
query_results <- new.env()

# Modify the query function to check if the query was already executed

query2 <- function(sql) {

  if (sql %in% ls(query_results)) {
    return(query_results[[sql]])
  } else {
    res <- query(sql)
    query_results[[sql]] <- res
    return(res)
  }
}

find_matching_columns <- function(table1, table2, key_list) {
  matching_columns <- list()
  
    get_relationship <- function(primary_key, foreign_key, table1, table2) {
        has_primary_duplicates <- nrow(query2(paste0("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ", primary_key, " FROM ", table1, " GROUP BY ", primary_key, " HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) subquery"))) > 0
        has_foreign_duplicates <- nrow(query2(paste0("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ", foreign_key, " FROM ", table2, " GROUP BY ", foreign_key, " HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) subquery"))) > 0
        primary_key_has_extra_elements <- nrow(query2(paste0("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", table1, " WHERE ", primary_key, " NOT IN (SELECT ", foreign_key, " FROM ", table2, ")"))) > 0
        foreign_key_has_extra_elements <- nrow(query2(paste0("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", table2, " WHERE ", foreign_key, " NOT IN (SELECT ", primary_key, " FROM sdc_analytics_prod.", table1, ")"))) > 0        

        if (!has_primary_duplicates && !has_foreign_duplicates) {
        return("1:1")
        } else if (has_primary_duplicates && !has_foreign_duplicates && primary_key_has_extra_elements) {
        return("many:1")
        } else if (!has_primary_duplicates && has_foreign_duplicates && foreign_key_has_extra_elements) {
        return("1:many")
        } else {
        return("many:many")
        }
    }

    for (col1 in key_list[[table1]]) {
        for (col2 in key_list[[table2]]) {
            cat("Comparing columns:", col1, "and", col2, "\n") # Added status message   
            join_condition <- paste0("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ", table1, " INNER JOIN ", table2, " ON ", table1, ".", col1, " = ", table2, ".", col2)
            join_rows <- query2(join_condition)[[1]]

            if (join_rows > 0) {
                relationship <- get_relationship(col1, col2, table1, table2)
                matching_columns[[length(matching_columns) + 1]] <- c(col1, col2, relationship)
            }
        }
    }   

  return(matching_columns)
}


find_relationships_between_dataframes <- function(key_list) {
  relationships <- list()
  
  table_names <- names(key_list)
  n_tables <- length(table_names)
  
  for (i in 1:(n_tables - 1)) {
    table1 <- table_names[i]
    cat("Processing table:", table1, "\n")
    
    if (!table1 %in% names(relationships)) {
      relationships[[table1]] <- list()
    }
    
    for (j in (i + 1):n_tables) {
      table2 <- table_names[j]
      cat("Comparing with table:", table2, "\n")
      
      if (!table2 %in% names(relationships)) {
        relationships[[table2]] <- list()
      }
      
      if (is.null(relationships[[table1]][[table2]])) {
        matching_columns <- tryCatch(
          find_matching_columns(table1, table2, key_list),
          error = function(e) {
            cat("Error occurred while finding matching columns:", e$message, "\n")
            return(NULL)
          }
        )
        relationships[[table1]][[table2]] <- matching_columns
        relationships[[table2]][[table1]] <- matching_columns
      }
      
      # Save relationships to JSON file
      json_output <- jsonlite::toJSON(relationships, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
      write(json_output, "./data_exploration/results/relationships.json")
      
    }
  }
  
  return(relationships)
}


test <- find_relationships_between_dataframes(key_list)
```

key_list is a table-name with a list of all columns which might be primary/foreign ID's in the second table.

```
key_list <- '{
  "table_name_1": [
    "potential_id_column_1",
    "potential_id_column_2"
  ],
  ...,
  "table_name_N": [
    "potential_id_column_1",
    "potential_id_column_2",
    "potential_id_column_3",
  ]
}'
```

This function is designed to test dozens of tables to find all the relationships between tables.The get_relationship function checks for primary key duplicates, foreign key duplicates, and extra elements in the primary and foreign keys. Based on these checks, it returns the relationship type between the columns. The problem is that it returns "many:many" for some columns that are not related.

I would appreciate any suggestions for improving the get_relationship function or any other part of the code. Also, please let me know if there is any additional information I should provide.